# How can l use Regex.Replace method within LINQ

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a controller with following method **getMail()**:

```
public JsonResult getMail(string id)
{
    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    string pattern = @"\bmem_id\b";
    string replace = "100";         
    var result = (from a in db.tblmail_type
                  where a.Id == Id                              
                  select new MailModel
                  {
                      subject = a.Subject,
                      Content = Regex.Replace(a.Content, pattern, replace);
                  });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This method is used for getting mail content. Before getting content, I want to replace a "mem_id" to "100" in the mail content. Default content is given below:

> Content = "You have successfully registered with Member ID: mem_id"

I have used `Regex.Replace()` method in the LINQ. But this code doesn't change the content. When I change this code to this form which is given below, it's work properly.

```
public JsonResult getMail(string id)
{
    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    var input = db.tblmail_type.Where(x=>x.Id==Id).FirstOrDefault().Content;
    string pattern = @"\bmem_id\b";
    string replace = "100";            
    string content = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
    var result = (from a in db.tblmail_type
                  where a.Id == Id
                  select new MailModel
                  {
                      subject = a.Subject,
                      Content = content
                  });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Why does this happen? Can anyone specify the reason behind this weird problem? How can I replace the "Content" within the LINQ?

Comment: First method you are replace each mail message.  Second method you are replacing all the mail messages.  The Regex is not in the loop.

Comment: What is the type of `db.tblmail_type`? I suspect the problem may be that in the first case your `Regex.Replace` is being executed in the database, which may have different regex rules.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I have stored different type of mail in the table called tblmail_type in the database. How can I replace the content within the linq query. Do you have any solution?

Comment: You haven't answered my question: what is the compile-time type of that property?

Comment: @jon skeet, Sorry I didn't get you. tblmail_type is a table in the MySql database

Comment: That's still not the compile-time type of `db.tblmail_type`. What does VS show if you hover over it? We don't know how you're accessing the database at all.

Comment: @jon skeet, When I hover over it, then it shows System.Data.Entity.DbSet<tblmail_type>

Comment: Right, thank you. That was all I was asking for. I suspect I know how to fix the problem, but I'm not in a position to post an answer until tonight.

Comment: Thak you @jon skeet for spending your valuable time for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any one of the following solutions,

*Solution 1:*

Unfortunatelly, you won't be able to send the regex processing logic directly to the database.
You'll need to get the `Content` from the database and then iterate over the list and apply regex.
This can be done by using `AsEnumerable()`. It breaks the query into two part.
First part is `inside part`( query before AsEnumerable()) is executed as `Linq-to-SQL`.
Second part is `outside part`( query after AsEnumerable()) is executed as `Linq-to-Objects`.
First part is executed on database and all data brought in to the client side.
Second part (here it is where, select) is performed on the client side.
So in short `AsEnumerable()` operator move query processing to client side.

```
var result = ( from a in db.tblmail_type.AsEnumerable()
               where a.Id == Id
               select new MailModel {
                        subject = a.Subject,
                        Content = Regex.Replace(a.Content, pattern, replace)
              });
```

*Solution 2:*

```
var result = db.tblmail_type.Where(x => x.Id == Id).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new MailModel { Content = Regex.Replace(x.Content, pattern, replace) , subject = x.Subject}).ToList();
```

*Solution 3:*

```
 var result = db.tblmail_type.Where(x => x.Id == Id).ToList();
 result.ForEach(x => x.Content = Regex.Replace(x.Content, pattern, replace));
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. These three solutions are perfectly working!